# Smoothing colors between vertices

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, minecraft

I've made a minecraft-kinda engine in C#, XNA. It gives a high fps and loads chunks w/o fps falls at all, but when it comes to global lights and shadows - i have problems.

Basically - in chunk's model creation loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
{ 
    for(int j = 0; j < chunk_height; j++) 
    { 
        for(int k = 0; k < 16; k++) 
        {
            // check if block (and 4 blocks around 
            // a current one (i, j, k), (i + 1, j, k), 
            // (i - 1, j, k), (i, j, k + 1), (i, j, k -1)) 
            // are covered and put shadows to block face's vertex colors. 
        }
    }
}
```

Result is old-minecraft-style shadows:

[image]

(With same good performace as before *screenshot is made with vsync on, w/o it fps is ~ 350*)

But i am trying to achieve minecraft's shadow, biome color and light smoothing ->

I am using triangle list because its impossible to use triangle strip for such stuff.
But vertex colors aren't smooth between any cube faces in this case.

So the problem is smoothing these vertices.Color -s to look like minecraft's one.

I made a simple algorithm, but it loads cpu too hard `(vertices.Count ^ 2 - sized loop)` so when you travel world and newly loaded chunks's shadows are computed, pc lags for 1-2 seconds, every time, while in mc there are no such slowdowns.

(I need the smoothing algo to be realtime and onrun because the main goal is to beat minecraft's performance (in minecraft's current minimum / medium graphics the result is achieved (~ 300 fps versus minecraft's 70))

Chunk's class (with the main problem), Helper class (misc stuff, used in project), Block class (Block-Type Base(used for creating and registering block types), block's model generator):

http://pastebin.com/GB1QqtdQ

P.S. Sorry for my English if it's bad, it isn't my main lang.

Comment: Hope you don't mind my edits.  Cleaner formatting will help you get better attention to your question.

Comment: Thanks, uosɐſ, i hope so

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be sharing vertices at all. If you were to construct the floor with shared vertices you'd get the right result. Remember, just because it's a triangle list instead of triangle strip doesn't mean the index buffer can't reference the same vertex for two or more triangles.

Comment: If by 'sharing' you mean - using 8 vertices instead of 24 for cube / sharing vertices between cubes nearby then i can't. 1) I won't compute normals in shader - its slow and too difficult 2) I need texture coordinates to be individual for each block's each face(i use a single texture file with different texture-tiles for multitexturing('texture atlas')) so by sharing vertices in such way i can only get artifacts and colored disortions of 'warp' instead of block textures. * hope i understood you right :/

Comment: What profile are you targeting? Do it have access to a GS? Most of your woes might go away if you do.

Comment: XNA Profile ? HiDef -> I don't need xbox / windows phone, i only need a clean pc version of my xna game but with good performace and graphics. Performace and graphics are achieved, the only problem is that function (SmoothVertices colors) - it slows everything down and limits me to pre-computing -> pre-loading the whole world (if its big -> gona need A LOT of RAM(VRAM). Less then minecraft, but mc has no pre-computing - their world is unlimited size).

Comment: Ah, it seems XNA doesn't support GS because it's built on top of DX9. If you were using something like SlimDX which allows GS access, you could use SV_PrimitiveID which gives you the primitive number so you can load face normals/tex-coords from a buffer. There'd be no need to duplicate vertices then and their position/color can be shared.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explanations. I'll google through tutorials for slimdx and hope - try to port my engine on it (i am almost 100% sure that it'll require much more time and skills, changes in code, but having the base algorythms and engine's subs polished... -> its worth it.)